# how to map inside another map in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops, object

Using the map function in React.js to get what's inside Mp3 from this json:

```
{
  "175": {
    "label": "Pub Radio",
    "icone": "",
    "Mp3": {
      "33278": {
        "id": 33278,
        "titre": "Ricardo Villalobos - Caminando",
        "intention1": "Doux",
        "intention2": "Doux",
        "intention3": "Doux",
        "langue": "Allemand",
        "visibilite": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "176": {
    "label": "Pub Cd/Dvd",
    "icone": "",
    "Mp3": {
      "33277": {
        "id": 33277,
        "titre": "Mano lo taugh - Primative People",
        "intention1": "Chaleureux, rassurant",
        "intention2": "Joyeux",
        "intention3": "Souriant",
        "langue": "Allemand",
        "visibilite": 1
      },
      "33279": {
        "id": 33279,
        "titre": "Foals - Late Night (Solomun Remix).mp3",
        "intention1": "Amical, complice",
        "intention2": "Amical, complice",
        "intention3": "Amical, complice",
        "langue": "Allemand",
        "visibilite": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "245": {
    "label": "Billboard",
    "icone": "",
    "Mp3": {
      "33280": {
        "id": 33280,
        "titre": "Techno",
        "intention1": "Posé, calme",
        "intention2": "Amical, complice",
        "intention3": "Souriant",
        "langue": "Americain",
        "visibilite": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is my map function :

```
  {Object.keys(extraitMP3).map((label, i) => (
    <li key={i}>
        <span >key: {i} Name: {extraitMP3[label]}</span>
            {Object.keys(extraitMP3[label]).map((Mp3, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
            <span >key: {i} Name: {extraitMP3[label][Mp3]}</span>

            {Object.keys(extraitMP3[label][Mp3]).map((idSon, i) => (
        <li key={i}>
            <span >key: {i} Name: {extraitMP3[label][Mp3][idSon]}</span>
            {console.log('Titre',extraitMP3[label][Mp3][idSon].titre)}
            {console.log('Intention 1',extraitMP3[label][Mp3][idSon].intention1)}
            {console.log('Intention 2',extraitMP3[label][Mp3][idSon].intention2)}
            {console.log('Intention 3',extraitMP3[label][Mp3][idSon].intention3)}
            {console.log('Langue',extraitMP3[label][Mp3][idSon].langue)}
            {console.log('Visibilite',extraitMP3[label][Mp3][idSon].visibilite)}
        </li>
    ))}
        </li>
    ))} 
        </li>
    ))}
```

Results are shown in the console as expected but also I receive a lot of other results as undefined. I think it's a problem of looping with map but I don't where is my problem exactly :

This is what I found in the console :

[image: Console]

[image]

Comment: Quick tip, avoid using same name variables (`i`) inside nested loops...That might be your problem...

Comment: i changed it to i, j and k but nothing happened still the same problem

Comment: `<span >key: {i} Name: {extraitMP3[label]}</span>` this will output an object, is this fine?

Comment: what do you mean it's not clear I deleted it the results don't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be simplified as

```
{
   Object.keys(extraitMP3).map(ids => {
     return (
        <li key={ids}>
           <span >key: {ids} Name: {extraitMP3[ids].label}</span>
              {
                Object.keys(extraitMP3[ids].Mp3).map(idJson => {
                  return(
                    <li key={idJson}>
                      <span>key: {idJson} Name: {idJson}</span>
                      {console.log('Titre',extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].titre)}
                      {console.log('Intention1',extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].intention1)}
                      {console.log('Intention 2',extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].intention2)}
                      {console.log('Intention 3',extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].intention3)}
                      {console.log('Langue',extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].langue)}
                      {console.log('Visibilite',extraitMP3[ids].Mp3[idJson].visibilite)}
                   </li>
                  );
                 })
                }
              </li>
            );
          })
        }
```

and using index as key is not a good way

hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer :

`extraitMP3[label][Mp3]` should be `extraitMP3[label].Mp3` (or alternatively `extraitMP3[label]['Mp3']` though not recommended by most linter)

But there are several things wrong

- You got duplicate keys which will mess up your React performances. Instead of `<li key={i}>` put an unique identifier such as the song id (for the last nested loop)
- As pointed by HRK44 you should use a unique iterator in each of the loop.
- Personal preference, I would use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to avoid this kind of problem in the future. This way you'll never get lost in long concatenated strings and it will be easier to debug...